# Libreoffice excel document

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I came across peculiar problem. Some of *.xls files are shared between Windows and Ubuntu machine.

Those files becomes unreadable after few times opening in ubuntu.

Comment: Do they contain anything special like VBA macros?

Comment: No. Its a simple excel document

Comment: Do they become unreadable on both machines? Which versions of excel and LO are you using? How are they shared? Can you identify something special about the last time they are opened on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, unreadable on boyh machines. LO 4.2.8.2, excel file version is .xls. I cannot provide you the error message I got as I have already deleted that excel file. File shared by server (NAS)

Comment: Does xlsx work better?

Comment: Have not tried sharing xlsx.